# Tell me where I can find a similar(images to 3D flash) service or a script?

Tags: flash, google-maps, 3d

About 1,5 years ago, met with a Web site. On the website you can upload multiple pictures of the object taken from different sides, and the site gave me a flash movie with my object but in 3D. Very similar to what it is now showing photos in Google maps.

Tell me where I can find a similar service or a script?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

do you mean something like photosynth?

Comment: Thanks for the tip. With your help, I found a more suitable site - openphotovr.org